# check if required JSON is valid - node

Tags: json, node.js, promise, require, bluebird

If i require a file as

```
require('file.json');
```

how do i go about checking if the JSON is valid? try catch?
I'm using bluebird promises so right now its just returning

```
 Promise.resolve(require('file.json'));
```

and bluebird catches if file is not found but i also need to check the JSONs sanity. I understand you can just pass JSON.parse to a thenable if file itself is returned as a string by FS or whatever but i dont mind caching and requiring would be faster

Comment: require is synchronous, there is no need to wrap it in a promise

Comment: Adding to what Esailija said - if you have a synchronous `require` when your server starts and it fails - you _want_ it to throw

Comment: I have to return a promise as its in a long .then chain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [Bluebird `try` function](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisetryfunction-fn--arraydynamicdynamic-arguments--dynamic-ctx----promise). If you use `resolve`, the `require()` call may throw before its result is wrapped in a promise.

```
Promise.try(require, 'file.json')
Promise.try(() => require('file.json')) // Bluebird 3.0
```

---

Alternatively use

```
Promise.resolve('file.json').then(require)
// or
Promise.method(require)('file.json')
```

Comment: This form will be deprecated in 3.0 btw : -)

Comment: @Esailija: Where can I find information about that? The `API.md` in the `3.0` branch isn't updated yet… Is it that we always need to use arrays?

Comment: It's just awkward. And with arrows only taking a function is not that bad `Promise.try(_ => require('file.json'))`

Comment: @Esailija: Hm, I like it. Of course there are alternatives using two calls…

Answer (score 0):

The issue with

```
Promise.resolve(require('file.json'));
```

is that it runs as

```
var obj = require('file.json'); 
Promise.resolve(obj);
```

which means that if the `require` throws, the promise has no way to catch it. Instead, I'd recommend doing

```
new Promise(function(resolve){
    resolve(require('file.json'));
})
```

This executes `require` from inside a promise, so the thrown error will be caught properly.